# One problem on random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

$e_i$'s are $n$ - dimensional random vectors and any two different random vectors are uncorelated . I need to prove

$$E[||\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k e_k||^2] = E[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k^2 ||e_k||^2]$$

Comment: Is $E(e_i)=0$ for all $i$?

Comment: @suresh: nothing is given like that

Comment: The key is that you need $E(e_i \cdot e_k)=0$ for $i\neq k$ which is the definition of being uncorrelated.

Comment: @suresh No, uncorrelated means E(XY)=E(X)E(Y), not E(XY)=0.

Comment: @user You might want to read again the definition of "uncorrelated" in your notes.

Comment: @Did Correct! Thanks. $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ for this case implies $E(e_i)\cdot E(e_k)$. One needs further assumptions like $E(e_k)=0$ or a weaker one like $\sum_k E(e_k)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In general,
$$
\left\|\sum_k a_k e_k\right\|^2 = \sum_ka_k^2 \|e_k\|^2+\sum_{k\ne j}a_ka_j\langle e_k,e_j\rangle.
$$
If $\langle e_k,e_j\rangle=0$ almost surely, for every $k\ne j$, then$$
\left\|\sum_k a_k e_k\right\|^2 = \sum_ka_k^2 \|e_k\|^2.
$$
Then take expectations, if you must.

The result is wrong if $e_k$ and $e_j$ are simply uncorrelated. For a counterexample, consider $e_1=e_2$ deterministic.

Comment: Yess! A downvote... I love it.